# Как заставить svg анимацию заработать в ie11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, ie11

```js
const Bar = ({ x, h }) => (
  <rect className="bar" width="3" strokeWidth="1" height={h} x={x} y="0" />
);
```

```js
 <svg className={className} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="43" height="43" viewBox="0 0 43 43">
      <defs>
        <circle id={circle} cx="139.5" cy="2369.5" r="21.5" />
        <mask id={mask} width="43" height="43" x="0" y="0" fill="#fff" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <use xlinkHref={`#${circle}`} />
        </mask>
      </defs>
      <use fill="none" fillRule="evenodd" stroke="#FFF" strokeDasharray="1 4" strokeWidth="8.4" mask={`url(#${mask})`} transform="translate(-118 -2348)" xlinkHref={`#${circle}`} />
      <g transform="translate(28 30) rotate(180)" className="bars">
        <Bar x={0} h={6} />
        <Bar x={5} h={12} />
        <Bar x={10} h={16} />
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В SVG 1.1 элементы `<svg>` не поддерживали [атрибуты трансформации](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#InterfaceSVGSVGElement). `transform: rotate() scale() translate()`

В SVG 2 предлагается, что они [должны поддерживать](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#SVGElement).  Но пока, этот стандарт не внедрён.

### Поддержка браузерами

[SVG transform](https://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20transform)  из таблицы видно, что **IE11**  не поддерживает транcформацию
и не будет никогда поддерживать, так как  Microsoft закончила поддержку IE11

[CSS transform](https://caniuse.com/#search=transform)  Таблица говорит, что `IE11` `Edge` поддерживают трансформации

***Поэтому, если необходимо создать приложение, которое будет поддерживаться IE11, Edge в плане анимации трансформации, то необходимо это делать в CSS.***

Ниже пример простейшей анимации трансформации вращения

```css
#rect {
transform-origin:center center;
transform-box:fill-box;
transition: transform 1s linear; 
}
#rect:hover  {
 transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" >  

<rect id="rect" x="50" y="50" width="150" height="150" rx="15" fill="purple" />
</svg>
```

Несмотря на данные [Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=transform) в IE11 так и не заработала анимация вращения.

В Edge работает, но как-то очень своеобразно.

Comment: На дворе 21 век... Кокой еще `IE11`????

Comment: @Air Ну видимо легче заставить разработчиков мучиться, чем установить у пользователей нормальные браузеры.

Comment: transform-origin: center и тогда работает не коряво

Comment: @aast4xov я с этого и начинал `transform-origin: center`, потом попробовал `50%` это ведь одно и тоже - center или 50% И результат один и тот же в обоих случаях, - очень своеобразный  по сравнению с другими браузерами Заменил на `center` что-нибудь изменилось?

Comment: кстати я вычитал сверху в комментарии сверху что оказывается microsoft выпустил обновление до -webkit-edge

Comment: @aast4xov Да, они давно собирались сделать это. Но, стоит заметить, что Opera давно перешла на движок webkit, но видимо не совсем удачно, у неё тоже остались некоторые проблемы с трансформациями преобразования